# Algorithm to get all the blocks to the top and right of the current chosen cell in Chomp game

Tags: java, algorithm

If I have a grid of 4x4, I want to get all the blocks/buttons in java that are to the right and top of the chosen block, how would I write an algorithm for it? For instance if the user picks the block "5" (row 2, column 2), then the blocks 1, 2, 3 and 6, 7 also change their color:

```
0  1  2   3
4  5  6   7
8  9  10  11
12 13 14  15
```

The algorithm should be valid for any grid layout. It should just change the color of the chosen block and all the blocks to the right of it, on top of it and to the top right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the blocks to the right are easy: keep adding 1 until you get to the end of the row.

All the blocks above is easy: keep subtracting the row width until you get to the first row.

That could look like this:

```
void ChangeButtonColors(int clickedButtonIndex, int numColumns) {

    // Integer division truncates toward zero.
    int startOfRow = (clickedButtonIndex / numColumns) * numColumns;
    int startOfNextRow = startOfRow + numColumns;

    // Walk across the row, starting at the clicked button and moving right
    // one at a time until we run off the end of the row.
    for (int i = clickedButtonIndex; i < startOfNextRow; i++) {
        // Walk up the column of buttons above this one, moving up
        // a row at a time until we go into the negatives (past the first row).
        for (int j = i; j >= 0; j -= numColumns) {
            buttons[j].Color = chosenColor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but can you explain your code line by line? I would really appreciate it! Especially what startOfRow is and how you calculate it

Comment: Start of row is the number in the leftmost column in the row you clicked. So if I click on 0-3, `startOfRow = 0`. If I click on 4-7, `startOfRow = 4` , etc. Almost every line is already commented. The only two that aren't are `startOfNextRow`, which is the number at the leftmost column of the row below the one you clicked, and the line that actually sets the button colour — I figure those are both pretty obvious from the code itself.